# Running a function on iframe parent ordered by iframe page

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I have PageA and PageB...

PageA contains an iFrame and pageB is inside that iFrame.

```
<iframe src="pageB.php />
```

On pageA I have a Javascript function that I want to run when pageB has updated.

My question is ... if it possible for pageA to know when pageB has been modified?

Comment: What do you mean by "modified" exactly?

Comment: Basically I update some records on the database on the iframed page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageB will need to notify PageA that something has occurred. You can attach a callback using window.parent.<my_callback>() from inside the iframe page.

(By the way, this will only work if both pages are on the same domain.)

Just as a simple example:

PageB (in iframe):

```
<html>
<body onload="window.parent.notifyChanges();"
     ... stuff ...
</body>
</html>
```

PageA

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function notifyChanges(){
             ...do something...
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ... stuff ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Satch3000 I added a very simple example.